# What does "get his head" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does "get his head" mean in this context?

> Penalty to Southampton!
> Vestergaard **gets his head** onto the corner, as so often, and Ederson parries. But Laporte yanks him back as he makes for the rebound and Saints have a spot kick

Answer (score 1):

Somebody takes a corner. Vestergaard "gets his head onto the corner" means he manages to put his head in the way of the ball which has come from that corner.

Comment: thanks. The verb "get" in this context mean to put, isn't it?

Comment: Please understand that the language of football commentary is a specialised subset of English which is a mixture of cliche, slang and hyperbole, and has little resemblance to conventional English.